# Cast array from jsonb_array_elements_text() to array of integers

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a JSON as following:

```
{
    "users": [1, 2, 3]
}
```

I am converting the `users` JSON array to a PostgreSQL array:

```
select user.identifier
from   jsonb_array_elements_text(('{"users": [1, 2, 3]}'::jsonb)->'users') as user(identifier);
```

This returns an array of `text` values. I want an array of `integer` values. With a subquery, it could look like the following, but this is rather clumsy:

```
select user.identifier
from   (select user.identifier::integer from jsonb_array_elements_text(('{"users": [1, 2, 3]}'::jsonb)->'users') as user(identifier)) user
```

Is this doable without an additional subquery? I can't find such syntax or utility function in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[you can aggregate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) straight away:

```
t=# select array_agg(identifier)::int[], pg_typeof(array_agg(identifier)::int[])
from   jsonb_array_elements_text(('{"users": [1, 2, 3]}'::jsonb)->'users') as u(identifier);
 array_agg | pg_typeof
-----------+-----------
 {1,2,3}   | integer[]
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `jsonb_array_elements_text` with `ARRAY` constructor and casting it into `int[]` like:

```
SELECT ARRAY(
  SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text('{"users": [1, 2, 3]}'::jsonb->'users'))::int[]
```